Typesetting `forall`s without breaking function composition
lhs2TeX's default polycode.fmt settings typeset forall as if it wasn't a keyword (see foo below). If I manually override its format to something like "\forall", it then still fails to format the dot after the type variable binders, typesetting it as a composition (see bar below). If I then change the format of dots, then it of course breaks normal function composition (see baz below).
How do  I fix the typesetting of forall without breaking the typesetting of function composition?
\documentclass{paper}
%include polycode.fmt

\begin{document}

> foo :: forall a. [a] -> Maybe a
> foo = f . g

%format forall a = "\ensuremath{\forall} " a

> bar :: forall a. [a] -> Maybe a
> bar = f . g

%format . = "."

> baz :: forall a. [a] -> Maybe a
> baz = f . g

\end{document}



It is hard to understand your question as  you just show some code and then an image apparently created by a different document. The code you posted shows this output where the dots are displayed (but > typesets as ¿

is the code shown passed through some preprocessor to generate the document used to generate the output that you show? It appeasr that you are showing tex not the original haskell source code but this isn't the tex that produced that output?

@DavidCarlisle I have the question tagged as lhs2tex which should imply that the code in my question is an input to the lhs2TeX program, which then spits out LaTeX. The problematic \circ for . is baked into the LaTeX output by then.

my understanding of lhs2tex is that it takes haskell input and generates tex so (since what you posted looks like latex) I assumed it was output of that program. As it is I don't know what it is (I haven't used haskell for decades but what you posted doesn't look like haskell to me?) If you post the generated latex document and ask how to configure it then there is a tex question to answer, if you post haskell and ask how to configure lhs2tex then really that's a haskell question and off topic, but as it is I really can't tell which you are asking

if I guess what the magic comments do, try  %format forall  = "\begingroup\ensuremath{\forall}\def\circ{.\endgroup} "  which should make forall typeset as ∀ and set up a group where \circ is . then at the first \circ  will make a . and end teh group so restoring normal definition

@DavidCarlisle This is lhs2tex input, in Literate Haskell mode where the lines starting with > are Haskell and the rest is LaTeX.  TBH since lhs2tex is a tag on this site, I didn't think I would need to explain what lhs2tex and its input format is as part of my question...

@DavidCarlisle I got it working with this idea of using groups, and it works as long as I have  %format . = "\circ" instead of %format . = \ensuremath{\circ}. I can see why the latter breaks the group trick, but how come it doesn't cause other problems that it's now used in non-math mode?

Sorry as you haven't posted the generated tex and I don't have lhs2tex I really have no idea what tex is doing or what input it is getting.

Based on @David Carlisle's helpful comment, I got it working by locally changing the definition of \circ until a . is encountered:
%format forall = "\begingroup\ensuremath{\forall}\def\circ{.~\endgroup} "

This works because I otherwise have %format . = "\circ", so in forall a. a -> a, the . is first turned by lhs2TeX into \circ.
Similarly, for RequiredTypeArguments it is useful to also turn function arrows into end-of-group markers, so that in something like f :: forall a -> a -> a the group is still properly closed off:
%format forall = "\begingroup\ensuremath{\forall}\let\oldto\to\def\to{\oldto\endgroup}\def\circ{.~\endgroup} "

